# beautifulSoup for look show only last result

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i currently try to learn python web scraping. I did everything exactly like in the tutorial. But the loop doesn't work. If I test it with print, it only shows the last entry.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import lxml

url = "https://www.moviepilot.de/dvd/dvds-neu"

agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=agent)

page_soup = soup(page.content, "html.parser")

ergebnisse = page_soup.findAll("li", {"class":"movie"})

for container in ergebnisse:
    filmname = container.a["title"]



print(filmname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you loop, you are overwriting the value of filmname, so it is probably only printing the last one. You need to add each filmname to an empty list from inside the loop.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import lxml

url = "https://www.moviepilot.de/dvd/dvds-neu"

agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=agent)

page_soup = soup(page.content, "html.parser")

ergebnisse = page_soup.findAll("li", {"class":"movie"})
films = []
for container in ergebnisse:
    filmname = container.a["title"]
    films.append(filmname)



print(films)
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your `for` loop is reassigning `filmname`, thus, only the value from the last iteration will be stored. However, you can use a list comprehension to store all of the necessary values:

```
ergebnisse = page_soup.findAll("li", {"class":"movie"})
names = [container.a["title"] for container in ergebnisse]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using selector as well:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

URL = "https://www.moviepilot.de/dvd/dvds-neu"

page = requests.get(URL, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})

page_soup = soup(page.content, "html.parser")

container = '\n'.join([item["title"] for item in page_soup.select("li.movie a")])
print(container)
```